# Is there any way to make this code more efficient using beginner-level knowledge (Python)?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

First basic programming college course and we were tasked with the following: suppose you own a burger restaurant and have to create a program that calculates how many burgers you can make, assuming 1 burger contains 1 bun, 2 patties and 1/5 lb. of bacon (0.2 lbs). The user will input how many of each ingredient they have in inventory and your result must be the **maximum** amount of burgers possible, **regardless** of extra ingredients (ie 1 bun, 4 meats, 1 lb of bacon must result in 1 burger possible due to only having 1 bun).

I believe I've done what was asked and tried to go a little further by calculating what ingredients you will be left with, but my code seems a little long and inefficient. The last thing we learned was for loops, and very briefly at that, so my entire code is basically nested if-else statements. Through research I also found elif statements but we 1. haven't learned about those yet and 2. I just don't really get them. While we are technically allowed to use any functions or operators we want, I don't really know much besides what we've been taught in this course, hence beginner-level knowledge in the title. Using this knowledge, is there a way to make my code more efficient and/or cleaner (maybe via the use of a for loop)?

```
bun = int(input("Please input the amount of buns you have in inventory.\n"))
patty = int(input("Please input the amount of patties you have in inventory.\n"))
bacon = float(input("Please input the amount of bacon, in lbs, you have in inventory.\n"))

total = (bun + patty / 2 + bacon / 0.2)
avgtotal = (total // 3)

if patty < bun:

  totalhamb = int(patty // 2)
  extrapatty = int(patty % 2)
  extrabun = int(bun - totalhamb)
  extrabacon = bacon - (0.2 * totalhamb)

  print(f"You can assemble {totalhamb} burgers and be left with {extrapatty} patties, {extrabun} buns, and {extrabacon} pounds of bacon.")

else:
  if avgtotal > bun:
    totalhamb = int(avgtotal - (avgtotal - bun))
    extrapatty = int((patty // 2) - totalhamb)
    extrabun = int(bun - totalhamb)
    extrabacon = bacon - (0.2 * totalhamb)
    
    print(f"You can assemble {totalhamb} burgers and be left with {extrapatty} patties, {extrabun} buns, and {extrabacon} pounds of bacon.")
    
  else:
    if (bacon / 0.2) < (bun + patty / 2):
      totalhamb = int(bacon / 0.2)
      extrapatty = int((patty / 2) - totalhamb)
      extrabun = int(bun - totalhamb)
      extrabacon = bacon - (0.2 * totalhamb)
      print(f"You can assemble {totalhamb} burgers and be left with {extrapatty} patties, {extrabun} buns, and {extrabacon} pounds of bacon.")
    else:
      print(f"You can assemble exactly {avgtotal} buns with no remaining ingredients.")
```

Comment: This is straight-through linear code.  There are no loops, and no call for loops.  Efficiency is just not a concern here.  As a style note, you can replace the `else:`/`if` pairs with `elif`.  That eliminated the stair-stepping and makes it a bit easier to read.

Comment: I may also consider asking on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). The folks over there love to review code as well. As you continue in your coding endeavors, I think you may find their forums a useful addition to your toolbox.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't take questions about code style or elegance here; please try [codereview.se] instead. See [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask for details.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been noted there are no efficiency issues here; however, your code *is* a bit too complicated. Not only you don't need loops, you don't need ifs either.

The number of hamburgers you can make is the *minimum* of the hamburgers allowed by each ingredient, so just compute those values and find the minimum, then use it to calculate the extra ingredients:

```
bun = int(input("Please input the amount of buns you have in inventory.\n"))
patty = int(input("Please input the amount of patties you have in inventory.\n"))
bacon = float(input("Please input the amount of bacon, in lbs, you have in inventory.\n"))
hamb = min(bun, patty//2, int(bacon/0.2))
print(f'You can make {hamb} hamburgers, and will be left with {bun-hamb} buns, {patty-2*hamb} patties, {bacon-0.2*hamb} lbs. bacon')
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help! Honestly, I had no idea that min() was even a thing. Like I said, very basic knowledge haha.